# Can localTime be added by 1 second continually in java.sql.Time?

Tags: java, time, localtime

In `java.time.LocalTime`, there is `addSeconds()` method.
Can it be used for adding 1 second continually?

```
LocalTime localTime = Time.valueOf("00:00:00").toLocalTime();
localTime = localTime.plusSeconds(1L);
String output = localTime.toString();
whiteTime = Time.valueOf(output);
```

I added this part of error message from Intellij.

```
00:00:58
respond to action of white: Black Time
00:00:59
respond to action of white: Black Time
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException
    at java.sql/java.sql.Time.valueOf(Time.java:109)
    at ui.TimerPanel.blackTimerTikTok(TimerPanel.java:71)
    at util.GameModel$2.actionPerformed(GameModel.java:87)
    at java.desktop/javax.swing.Timer.fireActionPerformed(Timer.java:317)
    at java.desktop/javax.swing.Timer$DoPostEvent.run(Timer.java:249)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(InvocationEvent.java:313)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:770)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:721)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:715)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:389)
    at java.base/java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:85)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:740)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:203)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:124)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:113)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:109)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:101)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:90)
```

It looks it makes an error when it reached `00:00:59`. How to make it `00:01:00` for continous counting for seconds?

Comment: Please clarify what you mean by "It looks it makes an error when it reached 00:00:59". What happens, and what did you expect?

Comment: What about `String output = localTime.format(DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("HH:mm:ss"));` instead of `String output = localTime.toString();`?

Comment: @KarolDowbecki I thing it's `java.sql.Time` because of the title of the question...

Comment: @Jon Skeet: When I run the related program and it reached 00:00:59, it shows long list of error message in intellij IDEA, java. I didn't check the error message carefully because I could not understand. I just understood that it does not work. If it needs, I will add the error message.

Comment: @deHaar, it's working. Thank you.

Comment: Yes, please add the error messages copy-pasted from your IntelliJ IDEA. Your question will make a lot more sense to other readers that way. (Just the first few if there are many.)

Comment: Yes, you should *always* add the errors to the question. "It doesn't work" isn't *nearly* as useful as "It fails due to these errors [..], which I don't understand."

Comment: I recommend you don’t use `java.sql.Time`. That class is poorly designed and long outdated. Instead just stick with `LocalTime`.

Comment: I have added "error message". I wish somebody interpret it or how to read it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that you are using `java.sql.Time.valueOf(String)` and depend on [`LocalTime.toString()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/LocalTime.html#toString--) format which may not print seconds because:

> The format used will be the shortest that outputs the full value of the time where the omitted parts are implied to be zero.

You should use [`Time.valueOf(LocalTime)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/sql/Time.html#valueOf(java.time.LocalTime)):

```
LocalTime localTime = Time.valueOf("00:00:59").toLocalTime();
localTime = localTime.plusSeconds(1);
System.out.println(Time.valueOf(localTime)); // 00:01:00
```

Comment: Because Ole mentioned that Time is deprecated, is there another class for set and print "00:00:00" in LocalTime? In other words, can you change the above code without using Time.valueOf()?

Comment: `LocalTime.of(0, 0, 0)`

Answer (score 1):

To add to what @Karol Dowbecki answered, if you need to use a String representation of your `LocalTime` you can use `DateTimeFormatter` to keep the format consistent:

```
DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("HH:mm:ss");

String output = localTime.format(formatter);
whiteTime = Time.valueOf(output);
```

This will output `00:01:00` when the time rolls around and not give you the error